# Evaluate $\int _{D}\frac{\sin z}{z^2-z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$\int_{D}\frac{\sin z}{z^2-z}dz$$ where $D$ is $|z-1|=2$

$$\int_{D}\frac{\sin z}{z^2-z}dz=\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{\frac{\sin z}{z-1}}{z}dz+\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{\frac{\sin z}{z}}{z-1}dz$$ where $\gamma_1$ is a closed ball around $0$ and $\gamma_2$ is a closed ball around $1$

Using cauchy integral theorem we get $$\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{\frac{\sin z}{z-1}}{z}dz+\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{\frac{\sin z}{z}}{z-1}dz=2\pi i\cdot 0+2\pi i\cdot \sin(1)$$

Can I use practical fractions and cauchy integral theorem to solve it too?

Comment: Are you familiar with [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)

Comment: Yes I wrote theorem and not formula

Comment: Actually, I mistakenly linked the wrong thing. I meant [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

Comment: @Guy You can edit comments within 5 minutes of posting them

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I know, but OP had already responded by the time I realized, so this seemed better.

Comment: True.  :D  Just saying it anyways

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  You mean "anyway," not "anyways," right?

Comment: Please add `dz` seven times to your post.

Comment: @Did correct, Thanks

Comment: "Correct", indeed, but not corrected. Why?

Comment: @Did replied to thank you but couldn't edit. Now It was corrected, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Partial fraction expansion gives $$\frac{1}{z^2-z}=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z}$$

Then, we can write

$$\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2-z}\,dz=\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z-1}\,dz-\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz \tag1$$

Note that the integrand of the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is analytic.  Therefore, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that $\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz=0$.

Using Cauchy's Integral Formula to evaluate the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ reveals $\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z-1}\,dz=2\pi i \sin(1)$.

Putting it together yields

$$\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2-z}\,dz=2\pi i \sin(1)$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just write
$$\oint_D \frac{\sin z}{z(z-1)}\mathrm d z=\oint_D \sin z\left (\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z} \right)\mathrm d z=\oint_D\frac{\sin z}{z-1}\mathrm d z-\oint_D \frac{\sin z}{z}\mathrm d z$$
Since the latter function is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ if extended by continuity in $z=0$ (remember that $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac {\sin z}{z}=1$), its integral is zero.

For the former integral, observe that because of Cauchy's formula,
$$\oint_D\frac{\sin z}{z-1}\mathrm d z=2\pi i\sin (1)$$